# What is the status of the FindMinimum method "QuadraticProgramming"?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

As a method option to `FindMinimum` `"QuadraticProgramming"` is still a valid option.  It has the advantage of being significantly faster than the default for such problems (`"InteriorPoint"`) in my experience.  It has the disadvantage that it appears to crash the kernel (V10.1 Win64) on some problems and its output is a little erratic (does not appear to be optimal in some cases in comparison to interior point solutions).

However my question is, is this still a supported method, as it appears to have been removed from the documentation (except for one mention in one of the `FindMaximum` warning messages)?

Comment: For completeness, can you give some examples where the method crashes or does not give a true optimum?

Answer (score 6):

Since the `QuadraticProgramming` method is not documented, it is also not supported (however, bug reports on it are welcome!)

It has been implemented some years ago using a rather dated by now version of the COIN-CLP library, which has a number of known problems. Future versions will hopefully bring optimization improvements and use more modern libraries.

Comment: I'll attempt to add some examples when I have time.